# Can the Einstein model of a solid be uniquely determined by the following requirements?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics

I am looking for thermodynamic systems (defined by their Hamiltonian, partition function, the expression for the entropy) satisfying the following requirements at equilibrium:

1. The particles that comprise them are distinguishable and non-interacting.
2. The extensive parameters are only energy $U$ and the number of particles $N$. (There is no information about the volume).
3. Energy levels for all particles are equally spaced.
4. It is equiprobable for particles to contain any amount of energy. I.e., all possible arrangements (microstates) are equiprobable.
5. N is large.

Attempt to provide a solution:

From the requirements: 1, 2, 3, 4 we conclude that the expression for the Boltzmann entropy is the one for the Einstein solid: $$S = k\ln\frac{(q + N -1)!}{q!(N - 1)!}$$

For each particle there can only be kinetic energy since they don't interact. There can be no translational energy since there is no distance or volume in the extensive parameters of the system. Additionally, there can be no rotational energy since, in that case, the energy levels are not equally spaced:
$$E_j = \frac{\hbar ^2}{2\mu r^2} J(J+1), J = 0,1,2,\ldots$$
All that is left is the vibrational energy, which is consistent with the requirements:
$$\begin{equation}
E_n = h f \left(n + \frac{1}{2} \right)
\end{equation}$$
Consequently, the "particles" are quantum harmonic oscillators. Since they are distinguishable and their number is large, requirements $(1), (5)$ the system is an Einstein solid.